# Cannot resume disabled index

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, indexing, azure-sql-database

I have disabled an index on my Azure SQL server database and then started rebuilding it with `resumable=on` option. After I broke the rebuild I cannot resume or abort it because index is disabled and I get an error:

> Cannot perform the specified operation on disabled index

The worst thing is that I can't create any other indexes as I then get another error:

> Cannot perform this operation on 'object' with ID 1918629878 as one or
>   more indexes are currently in resumable index rebuild state. Please
>   refer to sys.index_resumable_operations for more details.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to abort the online index operation using statement provided below:

```
ALTER INDEX [IndexName] on [TableName] ABORT;
```

Comment: thanks for reply. It says that it cannot perform abort on disabled index.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.index_resumable_operations` to monitor and check the current execution status for resumable index rebuilds.

```
SELECT total_execution_time, percent_complete, name,state_desc,last_pause_time,page_count
FROM sys.index_resumable_operations;
```

You can see the online resumable index rebuild operation after how much % completion, If the current status is `PAUSED`. You cannot drop the index while the index is in a `PAUSED` state, if we try we will get this error.

> Cannot perform this operation on 'object' with ID 1918629878 as one or
>   more indexes are currently in resumable index rebuild state. Please
>   refer to sys.index_resumable_operations for more details.

To resume the Online Index operation, need to use the below query.

```
ALTER INDEX IX_tablename ON [Table_Name]  RESUME
```

for more info check this [Resumable Online Index Create in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5759/resumable-online-index-create-in-sql-server-2019/)

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried this of course. It says that it cannot perform resume operation on disabled index.